# Error: Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
FSQL = "INSERT INTO Q_ClientSearch(SName, OName, Add1, Add2, Add3, TelNo, Email, NID) " & _
       " VALUES('" & M_SName & "', '" & M_OName & "', '" & M_Add1 & "', '" & M_Add2 & _
       "', '" & M_Add3 & "', '" & M_Phone & "', '" & M_Email & "', '" & M_IDNo & "') "

DoCmd.RunSQL FSQL
```

Note: All the fields in table are string variable

Comment: Seems you have a wrong underscore before VALUES

Comment: Everything looks ok to me. Does any of the variable have `'` as a character?

Comment: You may also want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042999/run-time-error-3061-too-few-parameters-expected-1)

Comment: If the field `NID` is numeric, then you don't need the single quotes around `M_IDNo`.

Comment: Non of the variables contains ' or "

Comment: The NID variable is defined as a string as it will contains both Alphabet and numeric characters ex T050163234567R- its an ID Number

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271) -- Add the output of `Debug.Print` to your question, if the problem isn't obvious from it.

Comment: Thanks for your tips was able to solve the problem with the Debug Print, Thanks again and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation will only give you troubles and is difficult to maintain. Please use parameters.

Create a query, copy the SQL below and the call it from VBA.

The query:

```sql
PARAMETERS [prmSName] Text(255), [prmOName] Text (255), [prmAdd1] Text(255), [prmAdd2] Text(255), 
[prmAdd3] Text(255), [prmTelNo] Text(255), [prmEmail] Text(255), [prmNID] Text(255);

INSERT INTO Q_ClientSearch(SName, OName, Add1, Add2, Add3, TelNo, Email, NID)
SELECT [prmSName] AS SName, [prmOName] AS OName, [prmAdd1] AS SName, [prmSName] AS Add1,
       [prmAdd2] AS Add2, [prmAdd3] AS Add3, [prmEmail] AS Email, [prmNID] AS NID;
```

To call it:

```vb
With CurrentDb().QueryDefs("YourQueryName")
    .Parameters("[prmSName]").Value = M_SName  
    .Parameters("[prmOName]").Value = M_OName  
    .Parameters("[prmAdd1]").Value = M_Add1  
    .Parameters("[prmAdd2]").Value = M_Add2  
    .Parameters("[prmAdd3]").Value = M_Add3  
    .Parameters("[prmTelNo]").Value = M_Phone  
    .Parameters("[prmEmail]").Value = M_Email  
    .Parameters("[prmNID]").Value = M_IDNo  
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
```